# ListView with Fragment within ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Current I have a ViewPager which have 3 different tabs(Peer, Sync and Share).
In the Peer fragment, it contain a ListView with clickable items. OnItemClick I wish to open a new fragment which will display the detail of the selected item,
But I am not sure how to properly implement this functionality...

Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.file_sharing_activity);

    // Tabs stuff ...
    this.tabsAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(this.tabsAdapter);

    // Create tabs bar
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    // Create tab fragments
    this.peerListFragment = new PeerListFragment();
    this.syncFragment = new SyncFragment();
    this.shareFragment = new ShareFragment();

    // Create tabs
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Peers").setTabListener(this.peerListFragment));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Sync").setTabListener(this.syncFragment));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Share").setTabListener(this.shareFragment));

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // When swiping between pages, select the
            // corresponding tab.
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    try {

        ProgramController.getInstance().initializeProgram(this);

    } catch (Exception e) {}

}
```

TabPagerAdapter:

```
private class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return peerListFragment;
        case 1:
            return syncFragment;
        case 2:
            return shareFragment;

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NB_TABS;
    }
}
```

PeerListFragment

```
public class PeerListFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener{

ListView peerListView;

public PeerListFragment(){
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_peer_list, container, false);
    peerListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_peer);
    PeerListAdapter adapter = new PeerListAdapter(getActivity());

    peerListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    peerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            //Display detail fragment here


        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Just start new activity which will display details. No?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would have a method on your `Activity` that would be called from `onItemClick()` to display the detail view, i,e, `showDetail(itemId)`.  The `Activity` would actually handle the transition to the detail view.

Now, since your `ViewPager` is in an `Activity` and not a `Fragment`, you have two choices:

- Have a `DetailActivity` that is started with an `Intent` from your current `Activity`. (Easiest option, but less flexible for tablets)
- Rewrite your `Activity` to put your view with the `ViewPager` in a `Fragment`.  Then the `Activity` would replace the current fragment that has the `ViewPager` with the detail fragment.  (Harder option, but you can display side-by-side in a tablet).

Right now, your `ViewPager` is in your activity layout.  In order to make the fragments work, your activity layout would just have one or two child layouts which function as fragment containers, then the `ViewPager` would go into a fragment layout.